# Bootstrap 4 increase card column count

Tags: css, sass, bootstrap-4

Is it possible to increase bootstrap-4 card column count? 
https://plnkr.co/edit/oIapj1imlMQ1M4vo1O5R?p=preview

This only shows 3 columns pushed to the left with 3 remaining columns empty to the right. I am putting this sass after the bootstrap-4 default styles:

```
.card-columns {
  // sm
  @media (min-width: 576px) {
    column-count: 3;
  }
  // md
  @media (min-width: 768px) {
    column-count: 4;
  }
  // lg
  @media (min-width: 992px) {
    column-count: 5;
  }
  // xl
  @media (min-width: 1200px) {
    column-count: 6;
  }
}
```

All examples I see do not successfully increase the column count, even using sass. If you know how, would you post a plunker example proving it is possible?

Answer (score 2):

This bootstrap solution is **buggy**. It's not bulletproof solution yet. You can read [here](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/card/).

> Why not work if increase the default `column-count: value;`?

Because `.card` `class` contain the `display: ***;` and `width: ***;` property. You should write custom `CSS` for this `column-count:` issue. You need to read this [article](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/c/column-count/). And Example is [here](https://codepen.io/katydecorah/pen/12c44feafcf5b38440c635560ff37d4b).

> My personal suggestion is avoid this css solution from production site. Hope this help.